# Changing links with JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

HTML

```
<div>
<p id="ui-id-1"><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    location.href="http://www.youtube.com";
    if($(window).width() < 958){
        document.getElementById("ui-id-1").innerHTML = location.href;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the link in the `<p>` when the width is 958 or less?

Answer (score 0):

You might also wanna add a resize function to handle it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var href = "http://www.youtube.com";
  if ($(window).width() < 958) {
    $("#ui-id-1 > a")[0].href = href;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't set `location.href` here, and where is the resize function you suggest?

Comment: Why can't I set the location.href here? @JamesThorpe

Comment: Because it will immediately redirect the page to that location, that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, I see, thought it was just his custom location object with a href, forgot the window.location.  Thanks.

Comment: And this code is now identical to mine - apart from the use of DOM instead of jQuery attr -  ah and the > a which I omitted

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `location.href` where you are setting it. It immediately will load the page you set it to. Perhaps you meant

```
function myFunction() {
  var loc="http://www.youtube.com";
  if($(window).width() < 958){
    $("#ui-id-1 a").attr("href",loc);
  }
}
```

You do need to call the function when some event happens.

For example when loading the page (assuming of course that jQuery is loaded)

```
$(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 958){
    $("#ui-id-1 a").attr("href","http://www.youtube.com");
  }
});
```

Comment: If he has jQuery and still using document.getElementById("ui-id-1") probably you must explain to him what jQ is. And attr and so on.